# Does "We can also use the subjunctive mood within the same sentence as verbs in the indicative mood" make sense for natives?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

I was reading the [Complete English Spelling and Pronunciation Rules](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=-4YAtAEACAAJ&dq=farlex%20complete%20english%20grammar%20rules&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPtpvm0ID5AhVzH0QIHWuGBrYQ6AF6BAgJEAM)  and I came across the next piece of text "We can also use the subjunctive mood within the same sentence as verbs in the indicative mood". The "as verbs part" sounds weird.

Comment: Hello Laurel! Thank you for editing my query, I would love to learn how to edit my question to avoid long links.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense. The subjunctive mood is an attribute only of verbs. So "verbs" is implied in the first part of the sentence.

The meaning is

> We can also use verbs in the subjunctive mood within the same sentence as verbs in the indicative mood

or

> We can also use the subjunctive mood within the same sentence as the indicative mood

The sentence quoted lacks parallelism, which means using similar stuctures to increase comprehensibility. That is not a violation of English grammar although many consider a lack of parallelism to be poor style.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: So the meaning is that you can combine verbs in both moods in the same sentence right?

Comment: Yes. But the whole thing is odd because the subjunctive as a distinctly conjugated form has virtually disppeared from English, and American usage is rapidly in flux in terms of how modals are used to convey what is conveyed in some other languages by subjunctives.

Comment: That's really interesting and amazing! Are you a grammarian ?

Comment: No, but I am interested in the American language. With respect to statements contrary to fact, I have seen modals taking on a role that they did not have when I was young. I am not sure that it is helpful to students who are native speakers of a language with a full blown subjunctive mode to describe English in terms of a subjunctive.

Answer (score 0):

If it is necessary that you be using the subjunctive, then use it but other verbs may use the indicative even in the same sentence.

Do you see what I did there?  The sentence above has verb in the subjunctive, another in the imperative aspect and another with a modal verb.  With a little effort I could include verbs in the past, or future tense, passive and active voice.

There is no rule in English that all verbs must be in the same aspect, tense, mood or voice.

But, don't use the subjunctive in new writing.  The subjunctive is rapidly disappearing from the language (and good riddance too)